# How can I put both in the same line?

Tags: inline

```
\textbf{BC Calculus - Step-by-Step
\begin{flushright}{Name \underline{\hspace{2.6in}}}\end{flushright}}
```

Comment: You can't with `flushright` ...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Next time please provide complete small document (called MWE: Minimal Working Example), which we test without to complete your code sniped to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

`flushright` is a display enviornment that can't be used inline, also I made the underline shorter so it fits.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent
\textbf{BC Calculus - Step-by-Step\hfill
  Name \underline{\hspace{1.6in}}}
\end{document}
```